# Mail details with Entry Id

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook mail Entry ID.

I want details of that Entry Id such as To, Subject ,Body, etc.

Emails are still in Inbox not moved anywhere.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
i = 0
j = 1
Dim path, FileName As String
Set currentExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set Selection = currentExplorer.Selection
Set currentMail = objNameSpace.GetItemFromID("000000000AB85207D8C3664BA439B3CE1603D186070019BED8705003484BACA686B84F9C6E880000006DE67E000019BED8705003484BACA686B84F9C6E880000428CEF9B0000")
MailTo = currentMail.To
MailSubject = currentMail.Subject
MailBody = currentMail.Body
MailDateTime = currentMail.CreationTime
attcount = currentItem.Attachments.Count

For j = 1 To attcount + 1
   'FileName = "\\wipfs01\ES Quality\Personal Folders\Mahesh\Tools\Sorting-Telus\Attachment\" & Atmt.FileName
    'Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
     Set chk = UserForm2.Controls("chkn" & j)
            
    If chk.Value = True Then
        path = SaveAttachment("\\wipfs01\ES Quality\Personal Folders\Mahesh\Tools\Sorting-Telus\Attachment\PO\")
        FileName = path & currentItem.Attachments(j).FileName
        currentItem.Attachments(j).SaveAsFile FileName
                
        Set currentMail = currentItem
        MailTo = currentMail.To
        MailSubject = currentMail.Subject
        MailBody = currentMail.Body
        MailDateTime = currentMail.CreationTime
        chk.Visible = False
    End If
Next j

'MsgBox MailTo & vbCrLf & MailSubject & vbCrLf & MailBody & vbCrLf & MailDateTime
End Sub
```

Comment: You should post some of the code. What you have tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Ohter way the question may be closed or not answered

Comment: Very very good! Now its good question

Answer (score 0):

Use `Namespace.GetItemFromID` to open the message using its entry id.